# loading text/plain script tag on demand

Tags: javascript, dom

Does/should dynamic tag creation also work for non Javascript MIME types?

```
var stag = document.createElement('script');
stag.type="text/plain";
stag.src = url;
$('head').append(stag);
```

I see no HTTP request in the debugger, and no content in the script ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers do not download scripts if the expected content-type (as specified in the `type` attribute) is not one they recognise as a supported scripting language.

Plain text is not a scripting language so will never be recognised as such by a browser.

NB: This is not specific to dynamically generated script elements.

Comment: @Aiden Bell — Not according to the test I just made in Chrome.

Comment: you seem to be correct, though I swear it worked before (hence the confusion and this question). *shurgs* cheers,